# How to reference same range multiple times and sequence together

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm doing the following:
`=HYPERLINK("some string"&'other sheet'!B3:B450;'other sheet'!B3:B450)`

The result: though the link urls sequence nicely, all the text is the same; first item.

How can I do this the right way? (I've tried `TRANSPOSE` on the second argument, and `LET` on the range, to no avail.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/hyperlink-function-do-not-support-dynamic-arrays/m-p/2028453), `HYPERLINK` has weird behavior with arrays, but:

`=HYPERLINK("some string"&@'other sheet'!B3:B450;'other sheet'!B3:B450)` will achieve what you want in Office 365. (Notice the intersection operator in the first argument.)

Comment: That's a very interesting linked post.